# Novel where a protagonist who doesn't like the idea of talent reincarnates in a magic world where talent is everything

Tags: story-identification, novel, isekai, reincarnation

The main character is a guy who worked very hard in life and hated it when people praised his talent because it felt like they disrespected his hard work. He dies and reincarnate in a word where only the descendants of the gods can practice magic. He is a normal boy without divine heritage, so he decides to discover by himself.

Comment: Was this a physical book or a web novel? And in roughly which year did you read it?

Comment: It was a web novel bit it was years ago, i can't remember, i've changed my phone and forgot to look it agon till recentily